# Reading variables from a text file C++

Tags: c++, fgets

For my robotics team I was tasked with writing a function that would allow us to store variable values in a text file so that we could update values without having to update the code. example: increasing the wheel speed. the format we have decided on is; whitespace or #, variable name, whitespace, variable value.

```
 variable1 1
#variable3 4
 setspeed 10
```

What I need to do is as a variable is needed my function would search the first column for the variable requested and return it. it has been recommended that I use fgets to read line by line but I am unsure as to how I would break up the line using our format.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow for "c++ read file" for examples.  There are too many variations so far.

Comment: Also there are plenty of libraries out there for this sort of thing already (e.g. [libini](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/)) - better to use one of these than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Most of the examples use `std::getline` and also `std::string` for string (text types).  Are you restricted to using `fgets`?

Comment: If this will be at all hierarchical use json or xml, and a library to read/write (like tinyxml). If you want to be fast, read the entire file in one go into a buffer and parse it in memory. I don't know why you would want to use fgets... you shouldn't wan't to.

Comment: You can read each whole line via `getline()`, then pass it to a `istringstream`, then extract the first field (variable name) and the second field (value) from the `istringstream`. You can then use e.g. `map<string, int>` in which to store each pair variable/value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading variables from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712194/reading-variables-from-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can break up the line in the format given by using a `std::stringstream`.  Here's an example:

```
    std::string line;               // A line of key/values from text
    std::string key;                // Temporary for our key
    std::string value;              // Temporary for our value
    std::ifstream stream(path);     // Load the file stream
    std::stringstream splitter;     // Prepare a stringstream as a splitter (splits on spaces) for reading key/values from a line

    // Make sure we can read the stream
    if (stream) {
        // As long as there are lines of data, we read the file
        while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
            splitter << line;                                   // Load line into splitter
            splitter >> key;                                    // Read the key back into temporary
            splitter >> value;                                  // Read the value back into temporary
            splitter.clear();                                   // Clear for next line
            variables[key] = value;                             // Store the key/value pair in our variable map.
        }
    }
    else {
        // The file was not found or locked, etc...
        std::cout << "Unable to open file: " << path << std::endl;
    }
```

Remember to include `<string>` and `<sstream>`.  I think you will also need `<iostream>` for `getline()` as well.

**NOTE:** I have a full working example of this which I can post, but I figured I'd leave the full exercise to you.  If you need more, let me know, but I feel it's best to learn by exploring a solution instead of having it handed to you.  Good luck on your robot!

**IMPORTANT:** It just occurred to me that my solution doesn't deal with the prefix white-space or '#' you express.  I would recommend either changing the requirements or you will have to use this as a staging point to deal with slightly more complicated parsing.  You could, for instance, check to see if the key is blank, and if so, the variable was prefixed with a space.  You would then re-load the key and append a space before it to get your final variable name.  Likewise, you could check the first character of a key for a '#'.  It's a little more work, but should be doable by modifying my example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry():name("\0"), value(0.0){}
    //Entry (std::string _name, double _value): name(_name), value(_value){}
    ~Entry() {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Entry& entry);
    friend std::istream& operator>> ( std::istream& is, Entry& entry);

    std::string GetName () {return name;} 
    double GetValue () {return value;}

private:
    std::string name;
    double value;
} ;

std::istream& operator>> ( std::istream& is, Entry& entry)
{
   is >> entry.name >> entry.value;
   return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Entry& entry)
{
    os << entry.name << " = " << entry.value << "\n";
    return os;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{   
        std::string filename = "test.txt";
        std::ifstream ifs (filename);

        if (ifs.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "Variable name:\t";
            std::string name;
            std::getline(std::cin, name);
            Entry entry;
            bool found = false;

            while (ifs >> entry)
                if (entry.GetName() == name)
                {
                    found = true;
                    std::cout << entry;
                    break;
                }

            if (!found)
                std::cout << "The name is wrong\n";

            ifs.close();
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Error opening file "<< filename;

        std::cin.sync();
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I believe, to start a variable name with a space is not a great idea. I suggest "%" and "#" to make a difference if necessary.